# Import Oracle dump on Amazon RDS

Tags: oracle, perl, amazon-web-services

I have dump files from our OracleDB production instance and I need to import it into our news RDS instance.

I followed the instructions from http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf (from p23)
and http://www.connecteddba.com/howto/MigratetoRDS.html (which is more or less the same)

The files are on the EC2 instance and I can connect to the RDS instance, the user has correct rights.

I correctly installed perl libraries to run the script

```
$ perl -e 'use DBI; print $DBI::VERSION,"\n";'
1.633
$ perl -e 'use DBD::Oracle; print $DBD::Oracle::VERSION,"\n";'
1.74
```

I've configured the variables to point to my RDS info - From the Test Connection of the http://www.connecteddba.com/howto/MigratetoRDS.html site, it passes correctly

```
$ perl test.pl
Got here without dying
```

However when running the copy script, it fails with the following error:

```
$ perl copy_to_rds.pl <myfile>.dmp
DBD::Oracle::db do warning: ORA-24344: success with compilation error (DBD SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: OCIStmtExecute) [for Statement "create or replace package perl_global as fhutl_file.file_type; end;"] at copy_to_rds.pl line 25.
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PLS-00905: object <myrdsuser>.PERL_GLOBAL is invalid
ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 6 in 'BEGIN <*>perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;') [for Statement "BEGIN perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;" with ParamValues: :chunk=8192, :dirname='DATA_PUMP_DIR', :fname='<myfile>.dmp'] at copy_to_rds.pl line 30.
ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PLS-00905: object <myrdsuser>.PERL_GLOBAL is invalid
ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 6 in 'BEGIN <*>perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;')
```

The script looks like this:

```
use DBI;
use warnings;
use strict;

# RDS instance info
my $RDS_PORT=1521;
my $RDS_HOST="<my rds instance>";
my $RDS_LOGIN="<myuser>/*******";
my $RDS_SID="<ORCL_LIKE>"; 

#The $ARGV[0] is a parameter you pass into the script
my $dirname = "DATA_PUMP_DIR";
my $fname = $ARGV[0];

my $data = "dummy";
my $chunk = 8192;

my $sql_open = "BEGIN perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;";
my $sql_write = "BEGIN utl_file.put_raw(perl_global.fh, :data, true); END;";
my $sql_close = "BEGIN utl_file.fclose(perl_global.fh); END;";
my $sql_global = "create or replace package perl_global as fhutl_file.file_type; end;";

my $conn = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host='.$RDS_HOST.';sid='.$RDS_SID.';port='.$RDS_PORT,$RDS_LOGIN, '') || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");

my $updated=$conn->do($sql_global);
my $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_open);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":dirname", \$dirname, 12);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":fname", \$fname, 12);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":chunk", \$chunk, 4);
$stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");

open (INF, $fname) || die "\nCan't open $fname for reading: $!\n";
binmode(INF);
$stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_write);
my %attrib = ('ora_type','24');
my $val=1;
while ($val> 0) {
  $val = read (INF, $data, $chunk);
  $stmt->bind_param(":data", $data , \%attrib);
  $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n") ; };
die "Problem copying: $!\n" if $!;
close INF || die "Can't close $fname: $!\n";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_close);
$stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n") ;
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: `create or replace package perl_global as fhutl_file.file_type; end;` This is not using proper syntax.

Comment: What should be the syntax ? do I miss the \ ? I follow the instructions from doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming here with the same issue, indeed the syntax was not correct and had to be

```
my $sql_global = "create or replace package perl_global as fh utl_file.file_type; end;";
```

the script on the link was not correct but it is correct in pdf file from amazon.

Comment: let's say i have a data.dmp file. I put it on EC2 Windows. I can connect from this EC2 to Oracle RDS using SQL Developer. But i don't know how to run script. Can you tell me please?

Comment: you would need to install perl on windows and run it from perl console or windows command line

Comment: I posted my script below. It didn't work. It said: Unrecognized character \x93, marked by <-- HERE after y $data = <-- HERE near column 12 at import-oracle.pl line 8.

Comment: don't post your script as an answer - create a new question and point to the new post from a new comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164717/whats-wrong-with-this-script-to-import-dmp-to-rds-oracle