# What's wrong with this script to import dmp to RDS Oracle?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to import my .dmp file to RDS Oracle in AWS. 
In my clean Windows EC2, i can connect to Oracle RDS using SQL Developer.

```
   # RDS instance info
    my $RDS_PORT=1521;
    my $RDS_HOST="testphat17.citmdnq1zckt.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
    my $RDS_LOGIN="testphat17/testphat17";
    my $RDS_SID="ORCL";
    my $dirname = ""C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\datadump"";
    my $fname = $ARGV[0];
    my $data = “201712010305_CLOUDTOSAI”;
    my $chunk = 8192;
    my $sql_open = "BEGIN perl_global.fh :=
    utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;";
    my $sql_write = "BEGIN utl_file.put_raw(perl_global.fh,
    :data, true); END;";
    my $sql_close = "BEGIN utl_file.fclose(perl_global.fh);
    END;";
    my $sql_global = "create or replace package perl_global as
    fh utl_file.file_type; end;";
    my $conn =
    DBI>connect('dbi:Oracle:host='.$RDS_HOST.';sid='.$RDS_SID.';po
    rt='.$RDS_PORT,$RDS_LOGIN, '') || die ( $DBI::errstr .
    "\n") ;
    my $updated=$conn->do($sql_global);
    my $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_open);
    $stmt->bind_param_inout(":dirname", \$dirname, 12);
    $stmt->bind_param_inout(":fname", \$fname, 12);
    $stmt->bind_param_inout(":chunk", \$chunk, 4);
    $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");
    open (INF, $fname) || die "\nCan't open $fname for
    reading: $!\n";
    binmode(INF);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_write);
    my %attrib = ('ora_type’,’24’);
    my $val=1;
    while ($val > 0) {
     $val = read (INF, $data, $chunk);
     $stmt->bind_param(":data", $data , \%attrib);
     $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n"); };
    die "Problem copying: $!\n" if $!;
    close INF || die "Can't close $fname: $!\n";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_close);
    $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");
```

The error said: Unrecognized character \x93, marked by <-- HERE after y $data = <-- HERE near column 12 at import-oracle.pl line 8. –

Comment: `“` are not normal quotes on that line. Make sure you never edit code with something like MS Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes character are not correct in line `“201712010305_CLOUDTOSAI”;`, probably some bad copy/paste from word or something else, change the line to

```
my $data = "201712010305_CLOUDTOSAI";
```

and you will fix this error

You also have wrong single quotes on line 32 `('ora_type’,’24’);`you will need to change with

```
my %attrib = ('ora_type','24');
```

Comment: Now it said: Bareword found where operator expected at import-oracle.pl line 39, near "close INF || die "Can't"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 32)
        (Do you need to predeclare close?)

Comment: Backslash found where operator expected at import-oracle.pl line 39, near "$!\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
String found where operator expected at import-oracle.pl line 39, near "$stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . ""
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)

Comment: (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Too many arguments for connect at import-oracle.pl line 20, near "'') "
syntax error at import-oracle.pl line 39, near "close INF || die "Can't "
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at import-oracle.pl line 39